# HoloLens 2 cannot find any sessions on LAN

Tags: unreal-engine4, hololens, unreal-blueprint, unreal-engine5, windows-mixed-reality

**Project**

I am currently working on a project which should allow users on the LAN to host sessions from an Android device and join them from the HoloLens 2. I have tried creating the same project in Unreal Engine 4.2.7 and 5.0.3.

**Issues**

I can create sessions from the Android device and they can be found from the PC and other Android devices on the same network, however the HoloLens 2 does not seem to find any sessions on the LAN. I am attaching the blueprint screenshot where I create the session.
[Create session](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6s0V1.png)

I have a content browser which would then display all the different sessions hosted on the LAN.
[Find and show sessions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ld4XX.png)

In the image below you can see that I am able to find sessions from the PC but when I run the application on the HoloLens 2, it does not find any sessions on the LAN.
[Find sessions menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kLPpp.png)

Comment: Have you checked your HoloLens device's IP address to make sure it's on the same network as other devices? And in **Edit->Project Settings->Platforms->HoloLens**, how do you configure the content of **Capabilities**? It would be helpful if you could provide some screenshots.

Comment: Yes, sorry for the late reply I fixed the issue by joining the session using the IP address rather than finding it and joining it.